# freemarker if-else or new if statement

Tags: freemarker

I have a site that will print out an article details to the user screen if the article has content.

So I am using

```
<#if article[0]?has_content>
```

Then the commands to display the content.

However if the article does not have content I want the screen to display something along the lines of 'The article contains no content'.

I am unsure of the best way to proceed with this, with best practise and what is the most efficient way.

Should I turn my if statement into a simple if-else statement? Or write a seperate if statement along the lines of -

```
<#if !article[0]?has_content>
```

(Im unsure of the placement of the !)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An <#else> would be more efficient, and more straightforward.